# Обновление тела таблицы (tbody) без обновления всей страницы c помощью mvc-контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Необходимо обновить тело tbody таблицы не перезагружая страницу. Страница формируется mvc-контроллером. Сама таблица:

```
<table class="table" id="pollingStationsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Station)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.House)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBodyPollingStation">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Station.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.House.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.IdPollingStation">Править</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.IdPollingStation">Удалить</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Для этого в mvc-контроллере, который формирует данную страницу прописал нужный метод, который принимает POST-запросы - GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class PollingStationsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly VoterCollectorContext _context;

        public PollingStationsController(VoterCollectorContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        // GET: PollingStations
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var voterCollectorContext = _context.PollingStation.Include(s => s.Station).Include(p => p.City).Include(p => p.House).Include(p => p.MicroDistrict).Include(p => p.Street);
            return View(await voterCollectorContext.ToListAsync());
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict([FromBody] ElectoralDistrictDTO electoralDistrictDTO)
        {
            List<District> districts = _context.District.Where(d => d.ElectoralDistrictId == electoralDistrictDTO.IdElectoralDistrict).ToList();
            List<int> selectStationsId = districts.Select(d => d.StationId ?? 0).ToList();

            IQueryable<PollingStation> pollingStations = _context.PollingStation.Include(p => p.Station).Include(p => p.City).Include(p => p.Street).Include(p => p.House)
                .Where(p => selectStationsId.Contains(p.StationId ?? 0));

            return PartialView(pollingStations);
        }
}
```

Подключил файл  , написал в нем JS функцию, которая формирует и отправляет ajax-запрос на сервер:

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectElectoralDistrictId").change(function () {
        var formData = {'IdElectoralDistrict': Number.parseInt($('#SelectElectoralDistrictId').val()), 'Name': $('#SelectElectoralDistrictId>option:selected').text() };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
        //    url: '@Url.Action("GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict")',
            url: 'PollingStations/GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict/',
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function (data) {

                $('#tableBodyPollingStation').replaceWith(data);

            },
            error: function (result, status, er) {
                alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Для обновления tbody таблицы данными с сервера создал представление:

```
@model IEnumerable<voteCollector.Models.PollingStation>;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict";
}

<tbody id="tableBodyPollingStation">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Station.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Street.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.House.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.IdPollingStation">Править</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.IdPollingStation">Удалить</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

После возврата объектов на фронт он попадает в for, созданного частичного представления GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict, но уже на 2-ой итерации выдает ошибку - error:

> [object Object] status: parsererror er:SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
> in JSON at position 2.

Попытался вернуть json вместо представления:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetPolingStationsByElectoralDistrict([FromBody] ElectoralDistrictDTO electoralDistrictDTO)
        {
            List<District> districts = _context.District.Where(d => d.ElectoralDistrictId == electoralDistrictDTO.IdElectoralDistrict).ToList();
            List<int> selectStationsId = districts.Select(d => d.StationId ?? 0).ToList();

            IQueryable<PollingStation> pollingStations = _context.PollingStation.Include(p => p.Station).Include(p => p.City).Include(p => p.Street).Include(p => p.House)
                .Where(p => selectStationsId.Contains(p.StationId ?? 0));

            return Ok(pollingStations.ToList());

            //return PartialView(pollingStations);
        }
```

После возврата из метода 500 ошибка:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> (Internal Server Error)

Попытался в методе контроллера явно преобразовать получаемый результат в Json массив - после конвертации и возврата из метода та же 500 ошибка.

Comment: [Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0). JavaScript после выполнения Post-запроса должен получить JSON с данными, а не частичное представления. После чего из этого JSON извлекаются данные и обновляется таблица.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, так мы же обновляем через mvc-контроллер, а не через api? mvc-контроллер возвращает представление. Мне нужно обновить часть представления

Comment: В контроллере следует сделать метод, который возвращает именно JSON как раз для этого случая.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, из api-контроллера json возвращал просто ```return Ok(JSONJojects)```. Попытался аналогично сделать здесь - мне выдало 500 ошибку. Есть какие-то нюансы по возврату json из mvc?